# Issues while installing mysql ? the installer does not progress beyond few initial steps?

Tags: mysql, installation, backend

I am trying to install mysql, & whenever I hit the installer file, it just does few initial steps - and simply does not respond or process furthher. Can someone help finding out, whats the issue ? I've added snaps below.

[image: Steps that's upto which it works fine]

Also later somehow I did manage to install it, but whenever I am running it. I am getting error as follows[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as the error message tells you it could be a memory issue.

Memory could not be written can be caused by:

1) Defective RAM.  Check the RAM with the "Memory" test on the boot screen or with MemTest 86+

2) Bad "third" party device drivers.  Try to review and remove "questionable" drivers

3) Too many apps starting up.  Try following a "clean boot" set up.

This thread might help http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/the-memory-could-not-be-written/21e2d589-04d7-42bd-9836-d089067edbb2